# How to manage Base activity with navigation drawer

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, fragment

In my navigation drawer I don wanted t wanted to use activity and how to use fragment in proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Impment FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener on your MainActivityClass. than write belowed code for as many fragment you want to replace in your application.     

          implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener
     activity_main.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.archi.intrisfeed.slidemenu.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




     @Override
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
            displayView(position);
        }


     private void displayView(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
            switch (String.valueOf(position)) {
                case "0":
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    fragment = new BrowseFragment();
                    break;
        default:
                    break;
            }
     if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

     }
```